Power BI - Number format (German format)
the visual shows the number as a numeric as well text (2,555 Tsd). However, I only want to see the whole number (2.555 in German format).
I don't know how can I only get the number in the German format? --> 2.555
Thank you a lot! :)

you can try to extract text before space.



